# Using Pytorch-cuda as base image for Docker

Tags: docker, pytorch

I need to use Pytorch with cuda gpu access. I use FROM  "pytorch/pytorch:1.9.0-cuda10.2-cudnn7-runtime" as my base image. Does necesssary python version also installed with this command ?

Answer (score 0):

From the DockerHub you can see how these kinds of images are built:
https://hub.docker.com/layers/pytorch/pytorch/1.9.0-cuda10.2-cudnn7-runtime/images/sha256-5dc11a9036bcb5b7950f4f8a43974057559278fa4bd87513cafd477fef9eb57a?context=explore

There you can see conda is installed. I would recommend using the conda that comes with it in the DockerFile you're using.